# Looking for a list of "english words" that exist in other languages, but with different meanings

Tags: offensive-language, confusables, cultural-phrases, international

I had a terrible misunderstanding with a semi-conservative Turkish woman who was offended when I said

> "Let's have brunch, and I'll bring some platonic female friends"

I'm told that in Turkey, "platonic" has a meaning of one person who deeply desires the other (sexually), but that is not reciprocated.  The English version is that of a non-sexual friendship, where lust isn't in the picture.

She thought that I wanted all these women present who admired me in that sexual way.

I don't wan to create these offenses again, and so is there a list of words that have a strong similarity to English, but with a different meaning?

Comment: None of my Turkish friends nor Google translate can substantiate your friend's claim. Platonik means exactly the same in turkish as in English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [*false friends*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend). Providing a list of all false friends in all pairs of languages is off-topic here, plus the answer would be endless and useless — but at least now you can go ahead and look up "English–Turkish false friends", or what have you.

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/yoursay/false_friends.shtml

My favourite is the Swedish "Knäppa" which is "take a snapshot" vs the Danish "Kneppe" which is a synonym for sexual intercourse. So when a Swedish colleague told his new Danish female acquaintance at the picnic to stand against the tree so he could take a snapshot, it was fun to watch ;)

Comment: @mplungjan heh, nice one. I quite like the [French](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitte#French) and [German](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitte#German) meanings of the word _bitte_ as well.